# Prerender Angular page in .NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, prerender

I'm implementing a feature with [EVO HTML-to-PDF converter for .NET](http://www.evopdf.com/) that should generate a pdf of an AngularJS built page.

I'm loading the data asynchronously to the page and currently my PDF doesn't naturally contain any content loaded via ajax.

I have to be able to access the pdf straight via URL so it's not possible to pass in the DOM to server with javascript.

I have implemented the [Prerender.io](http://prerender.io)'s .NET middleware ([by greengerong](https://github.com/greengerong/Prerender_asp_mvc)) and it seems to work fine BUT

1. The page is behind authentication (.NET basic MVC5)
2. I don't want to pass in sensitive data to 3rd party service
3. I'm developing in localhost/

The Question is: Is there any way to fake the prerendering or how would I implement the prerender.io service myself to run under the same .NET MVC application (to preserve auth tokens and what not)?

Comment: Why not just pre-render with Razor?

Comment: @JMK atm it seems that I have to go with Razor but the problem with it is that whenever I update the Angular-view, I also have to update the Razor view (double work, double sadness).

Comment: Not necessarily, why not just have one partial view (no layout) used for both Angular and Razor? Use @Html.Partial to add it to razor, and route to it in routeconfig to add it to angular via it's URL?

Comment: Hi @HenriHietala, Can you share your final approach? I am at a similar requirement and would like to evaluate this.

Comment: @DarshanJoshi I never got the solution for this. Our requirement changed so that the PDF wasn't identical to AngularJS view so I implemented a separate Razor view for PDF.